# How do I force SSH to only allow users with a key to log in?

Tags: ssh, sshd

I tried following the instructions here:
http://lani78.wordpress.com/2008/08/08/generate-a-ssh-key-and-disable-password-authentication-on-ubuntu-server/

to only allow users with a public key on the server to authenticate, but I can't get SSH to disallow logging in with only a username/password.

Here is my sshd_config file - am I missing anything? I already tried restarting SSH and the computer itself.

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details


# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes


# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768


# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO


# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes


RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile        %h/.ssh/authorized_keys


# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes


# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no


# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no


# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication no


# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes


# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes


X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no


#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net


# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*


Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server


# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no
```

Comment: FYI : Actually the sshd restart is not really necessary. The command ***/etc/inid.d/ssh reload*** should be enough.

Comment: Don't forget to uncomment #AuthorizedKeysFile and to copy the public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (and restart). Without this, it won't work.

Comment: If it wasn't true in 2016, it is definitely the case in 2019 that a restart is required; reload is not sufficient.

Answer (score 172):

By default `PasswordAuthentication` is set to **yes**, so explicitly commenting it in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart `sshd` has no effect.

You'll need to ***explicitly*** set `PasswordAuthentication no` to allow only Public Key Authentication.

```bsh
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no

PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

> NOTE (man `sshd_config`): `PasswordAuthentication` specifies whether password authentication is allowed. The ***default is yes***.

And restart `sshd`

- for sysvinit `service ssh restart`
- for systemd `systemctl restart sshd.service`.

Additionally, it is best practice to use the following directives (in order) `DenyUsers` `AllowUsers` `DenyGroups` `AllowGroups` for finer SSH access control granularity and flexibility. ->
Reference: [man 5 sshd_config](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5) ---> Ubuntu openssh man page does not include this any more as it absorbs openssh upstream docs (but FreeBSD, EL 7, 8 man page still have them).

Last but not least

> NOTE: be careful with setting `UsePAM no` as that way password locked user accounts (this is different from disabled / expired user accounts -> `man passwd` and `man usermod`) will NOT be able to login even if they have public key authentication configured in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Also we should have `UsePAM no`

Comment: @YAK I like to keep things simple and I prefer not to use PAM. But somebody can use a properly configured PAM authentication. I think this link is enlightening: http://arlimus.github.io/articles/usepam/

Comment: Consider also disabling ChallengeResponseAuthentication, see http://superuser.com/a/374234/2879.

Comment: Just go for the most `no` and the least possible `yes`.

`sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-redhat.conf; sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`


`ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`
`PasswordAuthentication no`
`PermitEmptyPasswords no`
`PubkeyAuthentication yes`
`UsePAM no`


...enables you to login with your private key only and even though the user has a password, the password login is always denied.

Answer (score 18):

According to this [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Shell#Force_public_key_authentication) about SSH keys and this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/374234/264031), you need to change these two lines in your `sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

Comment: What difference does the second line about challenge response make?

Comment: "It doesn't provide "additional security," per se. The term "ChallengeResponseAuthentication" is just an OpenSSH configuration keyword; it refers to the "keyboard-interactive" userauth method in the SSH protocol —Richard Silverman (fixunix.com)

Comment: For some reason, adding `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` worked even after applying `PasswordAuthentication no` and  `PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Answer (score 5):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, below settings worked for me:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

Finally, restart `sshd` daemon.

Answer (score 4):

The line you want is abnormally commented out by default in the sshd_config file.

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
--->#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

To disable passwords, change the `yes` to `no` and **remove the comment**:

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no
```